# C++ : subtracting unsigned values is unsigned

Tags: c++, c++14

In C++ the compiler reminds me that subtracting unsigned values is unsigned and so calling abs() is pointless:

```
uint64_t a, b;
if (std::abs(a - b) > 10) {
    std::cout << "Divergence achieved!" << std::endl;
}
```

OK, I understand that subtraction is addition, and I know in my instance that the numbers will be less than 2^63, so I `static_cast` to `int64_t`.  But the point of calling `abs` was to avoid writing

```
if (a - b > 10 || b - a > 10) {
    std::cout << "Divergence achieved!" << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: what is the warning? calling `abs` is not pointless at all (for the reason you already mention), so I wonder what is the problem you are trying to fix

Comment: btw you better fix the example to have no undefined behaviour by initializing `a` and `b`

Comment: The recommended way is to use signed integers in the first place, see the [C++ core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-signed).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 calling `abs` on an unsigned value is pointless because it will never be negative.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm but `a-b` is signed, or do I miss something?

Comment: If `a` is less than `b`, then `a - b` is likely to yield a wonky result (and probably a bug) if both `a` and `b` are unsigned.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 If `a` is unsigned and `b` is unsigned, then `a-b` is unsigned (from the [language rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Unless they're both smaller than `int`, in which case promotion kicks in and makes them signed.  That is extraordinarily unlikely to be happening here, with `uint64_t`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ups, one of this very rare moments where I think java is something nice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does abs(unsigned long) make any sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833289/does-absunsigned-long-make-any-sense)

Comment: @sv90 Any recommendation that wants to use signed integers for array indexes or sizes can kiss my **** since it is completely wrong.

Comment: As an aside, avoid `std::endl`. If manual flushing is actually needed, instead of just a pointless waste of time, be explicit and use `std::flush`.

Comment: I use `std::max(a,b)-std::min(a,b)`. You can make a template'd function called `absdiff` (or whatever) if you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) so you don't have to repeat the condition.  This will give you a reference to the minimum and maximum values so you can always do the subtraction in the right direction.  That would look like

```
uint64_t a, b;
auto minmax = std::minmax(a,b);
if (minmax.second - minmax.first > 10) {
    std::cout << "Divergence achieved!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is `10` going to be interpreted as a signed value here?  If so, it should be `static_cast<uint64_t>(10)`, to prevent large differences between the values being implicitly cast to a negative signed value.

Comment: @paddy It will be implcitly converted to a `uint64_t` via the usual arithmetic conversion

Comment: @paddy you can also do `10ULL` as an unsigned literal, if you want to be explicit.

Comment: `std::apply(std::minus<>{}, std::minmax(a,b))` or `auto[min,max]=std::minmax(a,b);` in C++17; C++ needs a cleaner way to use apply imho.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Wouldn't your use of `std::apply` result in `min - max`? That's the opposite of what is needed...

Comment: @sv90 true; wrong minus.

Answer (score -4):

Computers always subtract integers the same way - in a binary form. The assignment of signed or unsigned is an instruction to the compiler on how to treat the result.

Example: 1 - 2 (as 16 bit integers) will give 0xffff which is -1 for signed int, and 65535 for unsigned integer.

Therefore, if you want the signed difference between two unsigned integers, then

```
(int)(a - b);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: the OP asked how to do that, not why that happens